# Why control reaches to the end of a non-async handler function and then process the rest in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await

Kindly excuse my NodeJS knowledge as I'm still learning. I've following lambda function, which is meant to list the S3 bucket objects. In the function, I've `return allKeys`, however I noticed its value is always zero and that's because when the function executes, it doesn't wait for function to complete the execution and reaches out to evaluates `keys.length` and then return to the function which still in process.

**Code:**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const awsOptions = {
    region: "us-east-1"
};
const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsOptions);

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var totalKeys = 0;
    const allKeys = [];
    const SrcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    
    var bucketParams = {
        Bucket: SrcBucket,
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix: 'Temp/'
    };

    function ListS3ObjectsAsync()
    {
         s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            }
            else {
                var contents = data.Contents;
                totalKeys = totalKeys + contents.length;

                for (var index in contents) {
                    allKeys.push(contents[index].Key);
                }
                console.log(allKeys.length);

                if (data.IsTruncated) {
                    bucketParams.Marker = data.NextMarker;
                    ListS3ObjectsAsync();
                }
            }
         })
        return allKeys;
    } 
    var keys =  ListS3ObjectsAsync()
    console.log(`Total keys: ${keys.length}`);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a callback problem. Your code is expecting callbacks to work synchronously, which they don't. The code inside of the `function (err, data)` callback will **always** execute after the `console.log`. It's the nature of the event loop in JavaScript (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) for more detail on what the event loop is, why it's important, and how it impacts callbacks and promises).

Changing to an async methodology using promises should help things work:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const awsOptions = { region: 'us-east-1' };
const s3 = new AWS.S3(awsOptions);

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let totalKeys = 0;
  const keys = [];
  const SrcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: SrcBucket,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'Temp/'
  };

  let data;
  do {
    bucketParams.Marker = (data && data.NextMarker) ? data.NextMarker : undefined;
    data = await s3.listObjects(bucketParams).promise();
    const contents = data.Contents;
    totalKeys = totalKeys + contents.length;
    keys.push(...contents.map(x => x.Key));
  } while (data.IsTruncated);
  console.log(`Total keys: ${keys.length}`);
  return keys;
};
```

Explanation:

- making the `exports.handler = async ...` marks the function as async, which means it will return a promise. That means when calling it, you need to either use the same `async/await` syntax, or you need to use a `.then(keys=> { /*...*/ });` so that you'll get access to the keys.
- since we're in an `async`, the `await` keyword on the `s3.listObjects` tells it to wait for that asynchonous function to complete before going on. Keeps the code simpler.

EDIT: since OP is having problems with the sdk's `.promise()`, I'm including a promisified version of listObjects.

```
const listObjects = req => new Promise((resolve, reject) => s3.listObjects(req, (err, data) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  else resolve(data);
}));
```

This would be included at the top with the `require` statements, and then the only modification in the `exports.handler` code would be:

```
    data = await listObjects(bucketParams);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance and the explanation. However the code you suggested doesn't seem to be working, it ends up in following errors : `errorMessage: "s3.listObjects(...).promise is not a function`

Comment: Promises have been supported by aws-sdk for several years [see here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html). Are you using an older version of their sdk?

Comment: Well, I pasted the code as is on AWS console and the runtime environment is NodeJs 14.x. The code is throwing multiple error the first being `? ternary operator`, if I remove that then `errorMessage: "Cannot read property 'NextMarker' of undefined`, if I move it after `data = await s3.listObjects(bucketParams).promise()` then I get `errorMessage: "s3.listObjects(...).promise is not a function`

Comment: I didn't realize the aws lambda console had a problem with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Their GUI must not have been updated to support it yet. I've edited my answer to replace with older syntax. That must have been the source of all the other errors, since it was mistaking it for a ternary expression...I don't get any errors now when testing the code in a lambda.

Comment: I'm sure and thankful that you're doing your best to help me but the promise error still persist

Comment: do i need to make any changes here `const AWS = require('aws-sdk');` or anything to do with npm?

Comment: Well I can't explain your problem with `.promise`...I've set up a lambda on node 14.x, and it's working fine, code exactly as above in answer. Nevertheless, I've also included code above with an alternate way to "promisify" the regular callback version. Tested this code also in lambda.

Comment: Indeed there was no gap in your code and explanation. I deleted the lambda and started afresh and then... all worked with your earlier code, no errors at all